# Histogram plots in R

Tags: r

I have a data set like

```
     x = c(1,1,1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3,4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5,5, 5,5)
```

I would like to create a histogram of density of this data , which I want there is no space between bars, also I want to create a subplot inside thsi plot just for 1 and 2 values of the vector x.
How can I do this in R?

```
     hist(x, freq = FALSE, border = "gray", xlab ="", ylab="", col = "white", breaks = 10,
     ylim=c(0, 5))
```

Answer (score 1):

**Edited to reply OP's request**

You can try the following:

```
library(TeachingDemos)

x <- c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,5,5)

hist(x, freq = FALSE, border = "gray", xlab ="", ylab="", col = 'white', breaks = 0.5:5.5, ylim=c(0,5))

subplot(hist(x[x < 3], freq = FALSE, xlab ="", ylab="", main="", breaks = 0.5:2.5), 2, 4)
```

[image]

Comment: I want to have a subplot, but inside this plot for example above this plot.

Comment: @cancel.Thanks for you reply. How should we change the breaks value for subplot? Why you divided it by 2?I would like to have the same height for the first and second bins in the main plot and subplot? Are they have the same height?

Comment: I think you can search by yourself now.